# Why won't my php file run from my javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, execute

I'm building a website that contains a form, with a submit button at the bottom. When I click this button it is suppose to call a function in my javascript that sends a request to a php file that then sends information to a mysql server that is running on my laptop. This is the javascript file:

```
function registerUser()
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // Code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST",
                 "RegisterUser.php",
                 true);

    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

and this is the php file:

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '')
    or die("Unable to connect to database");


    $database = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database")
    or die("Could not select database");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('12', 'test');";
    $execute = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

?>
```

I have tried running the php file on my local host and that works fine, so there is no problem with the mysql server. However the website isn't running on a server, it is just opened in my browser from my laptop. I don't know if that is a problem. In the browser under developer, I can see that the php file is loaded, but it doesn't seem to be executed. So how do I execute the php file properly?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What do you mean "The website isn't running on a server, it is just opened in my browser from my laptop" ?  Are you opening the file from your fileystem using the file:// protocol?  You know that you *need* a web server to execute PHP files, right?

Comment: The button that is in my form in my html file. The button executes the registerUser() function in the javascript file.

Comment: Yes I'm opening it from my filesystem... Nope didn't know that I needed a web server... Not that I expect you to explain exactly how to do it, but is it hard to set up?

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  In the first sentence, you say that you have tried running the php file from your local host and that works fine.  So you do have a local web server running, or what?

Comment: @NiklasJensen In theory setting up a webserver is easy...  but that really depends upon your technical knowledge, the web server software you install, etc etc.

Comment: Thank all of you for your help. I'm kind of new to deploying websites. But from your comments I managed to figure it out. I was running my website from my file system I wasn't aware I had to deploy on my web server, but I have done that now and it works 
Once again thank you all :D

Comment: add xmlhttp.onload = function(e) {alert(this.response)} to see the message from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running my website from my file system. I wasn't aware I needed to deploy it to a web server. So I deployed it to my apache web server and now it is working :)